# Json to C# Deserializing with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

i have json string like this.

```
{
  "pax": {
    "children_ages": [
      7,
      0
    ],
    "adult_quantity": 2
  },
  "room_category": "Standard",
  "room_description": "FAMILY ROOM STANDARD",
  "nightly_prices": {
    "2017-08-17": "217.81",
    "2017-08-18": "217.81",
    "2017-08-19": "217.81",
    "2017-08-20": "217.81",
    "2017-08-21": "217.81",
    "2017-08-22": "217.78"
  },
  "room_type": "DB"
}
```

after i create c# classes from it ,i can get following kind of classes set.

```
    public class Pax
{
    public List<int> children_ages { get; set; }
    public int adult_quantity { get; set; }
}

public class NightlyPrices
{
    public string __invalid_name__2017-08-17 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2017-08-18 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2017-08-19 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2017-08-20 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2017-08-21 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2017-08-22 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Pax pax { get; set; }
    public string room_category { get; set; }
    public string room_description { get; set; }
    public NightlyPrices nightly_prices { get; set; }
    public string room_type { get; set; }
}
```

but this night prices is dynamic one.

```
"nightly_prices": {
        "2018-08-17": "217.81",
        "2017-08-18": "217.81",
        "2018-08-19": "217.81",
        "2018-08-20": "217.81",
        "2017-08-21": "217.81",
        "2017-08-22": "217.78"
      },
```

when response change then i cannot retrieve data for nightly_prices ,after  deserializing process.

I already tried this by adding dictionary types also.but it doesn't work well.

Is there any different ways to handle this scenario?

Comment: that doesn't look a correct JSON cause your `nightly_prices` should be an json array rather a object

Comment: @Rahul Looks more like a dictionary than an array to me.

Comment: Update root object `public IDictionary<string, string> nightly_prices { get; set; }`

Comment: @mason, yeah ... I see now. nice catch

Comment: json is correct @Rahul.i think it belongs to complex type deserialization.

Comment: @Nkosi it works now.thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: mason & rahul  thanks for your support guys